# Multi-level Model in R missing one predictor

Tags: r, multi-level

This is the R code I used for my model:

```
M4 <- lmer(Average ~ Region + (1|Participant),data=Theta)

tab_model(M4,show.se=T,digits = 4,
          title="Table: Model for the Relationship of Average Power in the Theta Frequency with 

the four Brain Regions")

summary(M4)
```

In `Region` there are four predictors: Central, Frontal, Occipital and Posterior. The output, however, only shows Frontal, Occipital and Posterior.

```
Average

Predictors  Estimates   std. Error  CI  p

(Intercept) 0.3473  0.0390  0.2709 – 0.4238 <0.001

Region [Frontal]    0.0938  0.0087  0.0767 – 0.1109 <0.001

Region [Occipital]  -0.1437 0.0087  -0.1608 – -0.1267   <0.001

Region [Posterior]  -0.0069 0.0087  -0.0239 – 0.0102    0.430
```

Why is that and is this something that can be fixed?

Comment: Central is the referent

Comment: See the linked question and answer. When you have categorical predictors, the first (alphabetically or by factor level) is used as the reference level to which others are compared, so does not have its own coefficient.